# Invalid_Signature on Bittrex Account API Request [javascript]

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, cryptojs, sha512

I'm trying to work out an api request for bittrex (account, not public) via ajax. Kicking back mention of Invalid Signature. I've already worked though the nonce, cors proxy and sha512 implementation. I seem to be missing something over here. Never had issues with ajax request, but haven't worked much with added encryption either.

Here are my setup variables & my request, followed by the error response.

Setup (w/ keys removed):

```
var apikey      = 'removed12345';
var apisecret   = 'removed12345';
var nonce       = Math.floor(Date.now() /1000);
var proxy       = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
var uri = proxy + 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='+apikey+'&nonce='+nonce;
var sign        = CryptoJS.SHA512(uri, apisecret).toString();
```

Request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    headers: {'apisign': sign},
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(bittrex) {
        console.log(bittrex);
    },

    error: function(xhr, status) { 
        console.log("error"); 
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

Response:

```
{success: false, message: "INVALID_SIGNATURE", result: null}
```

Comment: Take a look at the following [issue](https://github.com/ericsomdahl/python-bittrex/issues/69) on GitHub that matches your symptom, and which suggests a possible resolution.  The posts are less two weeks old -- it may provide relief and it looks easy-to-attempt.  In short, the suggested remedy is to simply refresh your api keys and related, with a fresh 2factor auth code, and then logout).  Good luck.

Comment: No-go on that angle, though I kept my fingers crossed while attempting. Thanks for the shot @DavidTansey